# How to fetch most recent transactions via ethers?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, web3js, ethers.js

How can I load the most recent 10 or 20 transactions from EVM?

I figured out that with the following code, I can listen to "pending" transactions. But I want to load all 20 latest transactions no matter which state they have.

```js
var url = "...some-node-or-alchemy-"
var provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url);
  
provider.on("pending", (tx) => {
    console.log(tx);
});
```

How to do that? The [documentation](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/provider/) is not really helpful. It shows only functions where I can load a transaction from a specific hash. But I don't know the hashes and need to fetch the latest hashes first.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Note this is V6 of ethers
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(`https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${process.env.YOUR_INFURA_API_KEY}`);
const eth_getBlockByNumber = async () => {
  const blockByNumber = await provider.send("eth_getBlockByNumber", ["pending", false]);
  const transactions = blockByNumber.transactions;
  const first50Transactions = transactions.slice(0, 50);
  console.log("First 50 transactions:", first50Transactions);
};

eth_getBlockByNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ethers EtherscanProvider](https://docs.ethers.org/v4/api-providers.html) api. `JsonRpcProvider` will connect you to a node in ethereum blockchain, `EtherscanProvider` will connect you to `etherscan` api

```
let etherscanProvider = new ethers.providers.EtherscanProvider();

// Getting the current Ethereum price
etherscanProvider.getEtherPrice().then(function(price) {
    console.log("Ether price in USD: " + price);
});


// Getting the transaction history of an address
let address = '0xb2682160c482eB985EC9F3e364eEc0a904C44C23';
let startBlock = 3135808;
let endBlock = 5091477;
etherscanProvider.getHistory(address, startBlock, endBlock).then(function(history) {
    console.log(history);
```

or you could sign up etherscan api and here is https://api.etherscan.io/apis

But in any case, I do not think you can specify the number of transactions. that implementation depends on RPC servers. if they did not build, you could handle this on the front end and return only specified number of transactions to the user

Comment: I got this error `TypeError: etherscanProvider.getHistory is not a function`

Comment: Is it for ethers v5?

Answer (score 0):

Pending and confirmed transactions are two very **distinct** transaction types, one is volatile and the other is confirmed to be part of the blockchain.

Having a connection to a node and using [Ethers](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--events) to stream `pending` events is a good way to get the latest pending transactions.

As for confirmed transactions, you could use a similar stream for `block` events to get the latest block number, and then checking for the transactions included in the block using an [eth_getBlockByNumber](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getBlock) call.